# Why is return confirm not working and inline onclick working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp net gridview linkbutton with css class confirmDelete and I have attached a click event using jquery like this

```
$('.confirmDelete').click(function (e) {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete!!');
});
```

but it doesnot work; it shows the confirm dialog no matter what we click it does stop the button handler.

On the other hand inline click event like this works

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" CssClass="btn btn-danger confirmDelete"></asp:LinkButton>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Oh yeah. Whoops :)

Comment: You should use event proxy to bind event, like `$('.confirmDelete').on('click', function (e) {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete!!');
});` for jQuery 2.x,

Comment: because your callback function in click event returns result to abyss

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$('.confirmDelete').click(function (e) {
    var confirm = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete!!');
    if (confirm) {
        // do all the things
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There no need to create a jquery function for this just write like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" CssClass="btn btn-danger" ID="delete" OnClick="delete_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

this will work like this:
When you click on the link button first a confirm dialog will appear if you press OK then server event will fire else server event will not fire

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it the click event within $( document ).ready().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.confirmDelete').click(function (e) {
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete!!');
    });
);
```